# IONIC 2, debuging ios application - emulate?target return 404

Tags: ionic2, visual-studio-2017, taco

I tried to build ios version of my ionic application which I build using Visual Studio 2017, but it seems it never can "install" to the simulator. The simulator is launched on the mac computer, but the application is not running, even I cannot find the icon in the simulator.
I suspect that it because the wrong naming of the target device.
I notice there is /cordova/build/.../emulate?target=iPhone+5 404 line on the mac's terminal, while when I try to the list the available target, it should be target=iPhone-5. 
I'm a newbie in ionic and I don't know if it is the cause of problem that make the application is not shown at the emulator.
If it is not the problem, is there anybody can help me to find out what is the cause so the application cannot be debugged (not shown in the emulator)? 
If it is the cause of the problem, then how can I change the command send from visual studio to the mac computer?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: check if it is working on android platform and please do this and reply me once..1.take project folder . 2. open in terminal.. 3. remove platforms 4. add platform 5. build via terminal.. 6.run

Comment: @varun aaruru: Thanks for the respond. Sorry for forget to mention that I developed the application in windows, so the android version is running as it should be. The problem is the ios version that should be build using remotebuild.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea about remote build.. but when I developed an app in windows and exported to mac, I just did above-mentioned steps and all issues were solved.

Comment: Thank you varun aaruru. I will try to build it in mac directly. I think it would need several adjustment.